# Does anyone know about a reference where someone has aggregated the cost optimization strategies for deploying LLMs?

Tags: reference-request, large-language-models

I am looking for a source where someone has mentioned the most commonly used strategies and optimisations to deploy LLMs on consumer hardware. I have read about layer offloading, quantisation methods using libraries like GPTQ and GGML, model pruning and distillation. I would love to know if people know about good blogs for this type of information. Lillian weng's blog seems to be one of the good one's that I know of.

Comment: Could you please add a link to Lillian Weng's blog for ease of access?